# Confirm() always performing code block in true regardless of value

Tags: javascript

As stated in the title...I'm trying to ask user whether they should continue deleting an item. My problem is irregardless of the value of confirm(..) line it always performs the code inside true for it. I've seen it return false and show the false code block afterwards it performs the true code block.

Here's my script code:

```
function deleteRow(clickedRow){
        if(confirm("Do you really want to remove this information?") == true){
            clickedRow.parentNode.submit();
            return true;
        //  document.getElementById("clickedRow.id").submit();
        }else{
            alert('This displays at false');
            event.preventDefault();
            return false;
        }
    }
```

And this is the button that calls this function:

```
echo "<button class = 'buttonDelete' onclick = 'deleteRow(this)'' />Delete</button>";
```

Comment: maybe you could try using three equals === instead of two equals ==.
I can not recreate your problem on my machine, maybe this is a browser issue.

Comment: tried === same thing still happened...used firefox and chrome for running these

Comment: The html for the button is not valid (extra apostrophe and forward slash). Should be `...onclick = 'deleteRow(this)'>Delete...`

Comment: @StephenMuecke sorry that used to be an submit button and changed it hence the slash and apostrophe ran it again without those and I still get same results

Comment: Works fine for me (chrome)

Comment: weird I wonder why it doesn't seem to work my side...should I post the entire page code? Not sure if it will help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it up now...seems it was an error in the form that I'm sending rather than the code itself