# Displaying 2 buttons inline

Tags: html, css

I've seen this question answered in different posts but the answers didn't seem to work for me so I wanted to ask. How does one post 2 buttons that each submit 2 different forms inline? I've tried adding display: inline and inline-block on the button and it didn't seem to work.

Here's my code:

```
echo "<div class = 'actCell'>";
    echo "<form id = ".$i." name='edit_company'  class='form-inline' enctype='multipart/form-data' action = '/DTS/index.php/Index/viewDocumentType' method = 'POST'>";
    echo "<input type = 'hidden' name = 'doc_type' value = '".$doc_type." '/>";
    echo "<input type = 'hidden' name = 'doc_id' value = '".$doc_id." '/>";
    echo "<button  onclick='document.getElementById(".$i.").submit()'/><span class = 'editBut' style = 'display: inline;'><img src =".base_url()."images/glyphicons_edit.png class = 'editImg'></span></button>";
    echo "</form>";
    //echo "<td><input type = 'submit' value = 'Edit'/></td>";
    echo "<form id = del".$i." name='delete_docType'  class='form-inline' enctype='multipart/form-data' action = '/DTS/index.php/delete_info/deleteInfoDocumentType' method = 'POST'>";
    echo "<input type = 'hidden' name = 'doc_type' value = '".$doc_type." '/>";
    echo "<input type = 'hidden' name = 'doc_id' value = '".$doc_id." '/>";
    echo "<button  onclick = 'return deleteRow(this)' /><span class = 'delBut' style = 'display: inline;'><img src =".base_url()."images/glyphicons_exclamation_mark.png class = 'delImg'></span></button>";
    echo "</form>";
    echo "</div>";
    echo "</div>";
```

CSS code:

```
.editAction, .actCell{
text-align: left;
display: table-cell;
}
```

Note: These buttons are part of a table hence the table-cell display on the div that encompasses the forms.

Comment: Please, make a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)-examples (without php stuffs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rearrange your HTML elements and have buttons separated from forms(outside of forms):

When you have to mention attribute values, they should be within double quotes. so use single quote to echo those lines in php

```
    echo '<div class = "actCell">';
        echo '<form id = "'.$i.'" name="edit_company"  class="form-inline" enctype="multipart/form-data" action = "/DTS/index.php/Index/viewDocumentType" method = "POST">';
        echo '<input type = "hidden" name = "doc_type" value = "'.$doc_type.'" />';
        echo '<input type = "hidden" name = "doc_id" value = "'.$doc_id.'" />';
        echo '</form>';
        //echo "<td><input type = 'submit' value = 'Edit'/></td>";
        echo '<form id = "del'.$i.'" name="delete_docType"  class="form-inline" enctype="multipart/form-data" action = "/DTS/index.php/delete_info/deleteInfoDocumentType" method = "POST">';
        echo '<input type = "hidden" name = "doc_type" value = "'.$doc_type.'" />';
        echo '<input type = "hidden" name = "doc_id" value = "'.$doc_id.'" />';
        echo '</form>';
    echo '<button  onclick="document.getElementById("'.$i.'").submit()"><span class = "editBut"><img src ="'.base_url().'images/glyphicons_edit.png" class = "editImg"></span></button>';
    echo '<button  onclick = "return deleteRow(this)" ><span class = "delBut" ><img src ="'.base_url().'images/glyphicons_exclamation_mark.png" class = "delImg"></span></button>';
        echo '</div>';
        echo '</div>';

set css to:

    button{ display: "block"; float: "left"; }
```

add extra div tag after last button:

```
    echo '<div style="clear:both;"></div>';
```

Note: span elements are display inline by default. so you don'tneed to put css to display it inline if you didn't change that before.

Comment: I bet.. it will also not work... First-hint: `<button/>` Second-hint: forget some quotes ``

Comment: Ah yes, didn't saw that @aldanux. I was just mentioning a way to do.

Comment: and your css style: remove the double quotes

Comment: the code actually worked by displaying the buttons inline as I wanted but now the delete button is no longer submitting since it's calling a javascript function that has a confirm question with a true code-block of clickedRow.parentNode.submit()

Comment: Given the fact that it does answer the question though I'll take it as the answer. Thanks!

Comment: Btw using display: block with float: left (or right) is redundant. When setting an element to float it is also automatically force set as a block element.

Comment: @user3580218 I saw your `deleteRow()` function in another question here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23692131/confirm-always-performing-code-block-in-true-regardless-of-value. It uses `clickedRow.parentNode.submit();` in the function. so replace it with `document.getElementById(clickedRow).submit()` and in your button, it should be `"return deleteRow(del'.$i.')"`

Comment: I figured out a solution to the problem by just putting a name on the button similar to the form name and doing document.getElementById(clickedRow.name).submit()